# Print Jobs Stuck in Queue Won't Delete

Tags: windows-10, printing

Occasionally a job will get stuck in the windows print queue because the printer is not responding.  I will try to delete it but the job never leaves the queue and requires the computer to be restarted.

Things I've tried:

- Canceling the Job
- Restarting the print spooler service
- Stopping the print spooler, checking C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS (nothing there) and starting the spooler back up.

The jobs will remain in the queue with the status 'Deleting' until the machine has been rebooted.

Background info:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Intel Nuc

Answer (score 2):

Stop the Print Spooler

Uninstall the Printer, remove the Driver using Devices and Printer (Driver tab)

Restart and do a full install of the printer again.

Removing the printer AND driver and a complete reinstall fixes the majority of Print Spooler issues.

Comment: This. I've had to do this many-a-time, when working in Primary Care PC support.